# How to add an image to combo box?

Tags: c#, image, combobox

1. i have added Images to "Projects -> Resources"
2. and added like this
           this.imageList.Images.Add(AmadaWeldCam.Properties.Resources.Image1);
           this.imageList.Images.Add(AmadaWeldCam.Properties.Resources.Image2);
3. and setkeyname
           this.imageList.Images.SetKeyName(0, "Image1.png");
           this.imageList.Images.SetKeyName(1, "Image2.png");

i got the following errors while open the Form

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: '0' is not a valid value for 'index'. 
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: '1' is not a valid value for 'index'.

what could be the problem?